# python threads synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I have a python app that goes like this:

1. main thread is GUI
2. there is a config thread that is started even before GUI
3. config thread starts a few others independent threads

=> How can I let GUI know that all of those "independent threads" (3.) have finished? How do I detect it in my program (just give me general idea)

I know about Semaphores but I couldnt figure it out, since this is a little more logically complicated than to what I am used to when dealing with threads.

PS all those threads are QThreads from PyQt if that is of any importance but I doubt it.

thanks

Comment: Make sure all those other threads have started, then do `for t in other_threads: t.wait()` will block until other_threads have completed (http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html#wait).  Use `t.join()` if using the `threading` module.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Queue module*](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue) is great for communicating between threads without worrying about locks or other mutexes.  It features a pair of methods, task_done() and join() that are used to signal the completion of tasks and to wait for all tasks to be completed.  Here's an example from the docs:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: I think he just wants to know when these threads are done.  `for t in threads: t.join()` (Or in the case of `QThreads`, `.wait()`) would work fine for that.

Comment: I ended up using a simple counter that I access in mutex. Once that counter is equal to number of threads I call my function. So the workflow goes like this:
1. start all threads
2. each of the little threads calls my method once nearning finish
3. it adds 1 to global counter in mutex
4. once the global variable is equal to number of threads the code is executed